# fatal error: winsock: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c

I have been trying to compile multiple C and C++ scripts on a kali VM and 99% of the time I get an error like this:

```
test.cpp:39:10: fatal error: winsock: No such file or directory
#include <winsock>
```

It will do the same for Iostream too, I cannot find anything that has helped me fix this and I need to be able to comple and run these programs.

Comment: Hint: winsock is short for Windows Sockets.

Comment: Obviously, you don't have your project's header file include paths setup correctly, which would explain why `<iostream>` fails. But FYI, `<winsock>` will not work anyway, you need to use `<winsock.h>` instead

Comment: Some headers have the `.h` extension and this is not optional.

Comment: Also C and C++ are not "scripts", but programs. This distinction is made because you generally need to compile and link these before they do anything useful, a contrast between things like Python that can run as-is.

Answer (score -1):

You need to download and install the sdk platform